# Toggle function blocking image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this toogle function on my website for the mobile view

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("ul").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

but it seems to be blocking my image gallery on my page
which is also done with javascript, when i delete the function the image gallery works perfectly.

just wondering if anyone could help me as ive already done several pages with this and don't want to have to go back through all of them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give us a demo, or post your URL so we can actually see the rest of the code? Off the top of my head it sounds like you have a JS error somewhere which is causing the engine to halt.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").on("click",function(){
     $("ul").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

I recommend you to use

```
$(selector).on('click'/'change'/'hover', function(){//handler })
```

instead of

```
$(selector).click/.hover/.change(function() {//handler});
```

Please google about this

Or replace :

```
     $(document).ready
```

with:

```
(function($) { // your code here} )(jQuery)
```

Comment: thanks for your help guys! manage to find a better script, now it works perfectly